# Dr. Jekyll & Mr. Hyde unknown ( Biblical?) Reference

Tags: phrases, british-english, history

Okay, so I am an *avid* reader, and have recently undertaken a challenge to read Dr. Jekyll & Mr. Hyde, along with Robert Louis Stevenson's other literature. Having recently completed Jekyll & Hyde, which, during my reading, I had marked a few phrases or terms that I did not know and came across this text:

(pg.69)   "Small indeed was my appetite. This inexplicable incident, this reversal of my previous experience, seemed, like the Babylonian finger on the wall, to be spelling out the letters of my judgement; and I began to reflect more seriously than ever before on the issues and possibilities of my double existence."

I have no clue as to what the late Robert Stevenson is referring to by the seemingly Christian-based Babylonian "Doom Hand", although I have heard there have been paintings of it by the likes of Rembrandt & John Martin.

Comment: This appears to be similar to [_the writing on the wall_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_writing_on_the_wall)

Comment: See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169529/the-moving-finger-writes-even-in-heaven) which asks about another reference to the Book of Daniel.

Comment: [Daniel 5.5](http://www.biblesociety.org.uk/the-bible/search-the-bible/ESV/Dan/5/5/) *Immediately the fingers of a human hand appeared and wrote on the plaster of the wall of the king's palace, opposite the lampstand. And the king saw the hand as it wrote.* But I can't find a single instance of *Babylonian finger* in Google Books that's not directly or indirectly related to OP's specific text, so I don't think this is meaningfully about *English*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a (very old) one-off allusion to a biblical passage unknown to most current speakers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a one-off allusion to a Biblical passage widely known to many if only because of the well known adage 'The writing's on the wall'. The incident (the finger on the wall affair), not the finger, was Babylonian.

Comment: Strange, that our "avid reader" has never heard of this. Stranger still that FumbleFingers thinks it is "unknown to most current speakers". What has become of literacy?

Comment: I would use a clever allusion to classical mythology and biblical studies to comment on this, but nobody would understand it.

Answer (score 4):

This allusion is an example of “handwriting on the wall”, which warns of future events, usually calamitous.  The related Biblical passage is from [Daniel, chapter 5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%205), a chapter that portends the end of King Belshazzar's reign.

Verse 5 describes the event.  From [Biblegateway.com](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%205):

> Suddenly the fingers of a human hand appeared and wrote on the plaster
>   of the wall, near the lampstand in the royal palace. The king watched
>   the hand as it wrote.

Verses 25 through 28 specify what was written.

> 25 “This is the inscription that was written:
>
> mene, mene, tekel, parsin
>
> 26 “Here is what these words mean:
>
> Mene[e]: God has numbered the days of your reign and brought it to an
>   end.
>
> 27 Tekel[f]: You have been weighed on the scales and found wanting.
>
> 28 Peres[g]: Your kingdom is divided and given to the Medes and
>   Persians.”