# Unable to understand this quote

Tags: poetry, meaning

> The Moving Finger writes; and, having writ,
>   Moves on: nor all thy Piety nor Wit
>   Shall lure it back to cancel half a Line,
>   Nor all thy Tears wash out a Word of it.
>
> *The Rubaiyat of Omar Khayyam* trans Edward FitzGerald

I need a line by line explanation

Comment: http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-meaning-ofthis-rubai-moving-finger-writes-360306,

Comment: the link which you have provided I have already read that.In that only first line is  explain and a small summary of poem is given.I am unable to understand last 3 lines

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169529/the-moving-finger-writes-even-in-heaven

Comment: sorry the link you provided is something else

Comment: Actually, it isn't. Read my answer there and all the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The moving finger writes, and having written,
>   it moves on. None of your piety and knowledge
>   will entice it (the hand) back to erase even half a line of what it wrote;
>   nor can all your tears wash away a single word.

What the hand has written, it has written; and that writing cannot be changed.

Comment: That was too literal.  It means 'what's done is done' (entropy increases).

Comment: @AmI We don't do interpretation; that's off-topic. We only do literal.